# Mysql parse dates in this format: 2012-03-27T03:03:00?

Tags: mysql, datetime, hour

I have a table which stores times as a simple varchar, in a format that looks like "2012-03-27T03:03:00".

I'd like to use mysql's date functions with this data.  Some functions work fine, i.e.

```
mysql> select year('2012-03-14T11:28:32'), month('2012-03-14T11:28:32');
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| year('2012-03-14T11:28:32') | month('2012-03-14T11:28:32') |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|                        2012 |                            3 |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But hour and minute functions fail:

```
mysql> select hour('2012-03-14T11:28:32'), minute('2012-03-14T11:28:32');
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| hour('2012-03-14T11:28:32') | minute('2012-03-14T11:28:32') |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                           0 |                            20 |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

I believe it is the 'T' in my date format that screws up mysql.  If I manually replace it with a space, the functions work:

```
mysql> select hour('2012-03-14 11:28:32'), minute('2012-03-14 11:28:32');
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
| hour('2012-03-14 11:28:32') | minute('2012-03-14 11:28:32') |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
|                          11 |                            28 |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there some simple way I can tell mysql to parse the 'T'???

Comment: ISO 8601 vs ISO 9075! (That's the wonderful thing about standards; there are so many to choose from.  And be glad you aren't dealing with ISO 9945 as well.)

Comment: [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: In addition to the answers already provided, if you wanted the `HOUR()`, `MINUTE()`, etc. functions to work directly on the time field without it having to go through `STR_TO_DATE()`, you can just parse the 'T' out of your entire table via `UPDATE table SET timefield = REPLACE(timefield, 'T', ' ')`. Then all values become a valid DATETIME string.

Answer (score 0):

Those MySQL Date and Time functions ([`HOUR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour), for example) require a *specific part* of the timestamp.

Therefore, you need to use [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) and [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract the time and date, respectively, from the passed timestamp:

Extracting the time:

```
select hour(time('2012-03-14T11:28:32')), minute(time('2012-03-14T11:28:32'));
```

Extracting the date:

```
select year(date('2012-03-14T11:28:32')), month(date('2012-03-14T11:28:32'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  Same problem described in the original question.

Comment: What are the two warnings you get when running your second query?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('2012-03-14T11:28:32','%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s'))
```

STR_TO_DATE is pretty good about returning NULL for rubbish dates like this non-leap-year item.

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2011-02-29T11:28:32','%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s')
```

It also lets you do stuff like

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2011-02-28T11:28:32','%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s') + INTERVAL 1 QUARTER
```

or

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2011-02-28T11:28:32','%Y-%m-%dT%k:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 35 MINUTE
```

and have everything work right.

See here for the conversion specifiers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format